# For array of objects, how can I add or change a key to the main array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to add "gridColumnEvents" as main key to the below code so that the output will have "gridColumnEvents":[{ all the objects below in here}]. How can I achieve this?

```
[{
    "value": "720",
    "command": "SetGridCellValue",
    "columnID": "28"
},
{
    "value": "331-4014",
    "command": "SetGridCellValue",
    "columnID": "29"
},
{
    "value": "CAR",
    "command": "SetGridCellValue",
    "columnID": "27"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a object using object literal and define key and value pair as per your requirement.

```js
let arr = [{"value": "720","command": "SetGridCellValue","columnID": "28"},{"value": "331-4014","command": "SetGridCellValue","columnID": "29"},{"value": "CAR","command": "SetGridCellValue","columnID": "27"}]

let obj = {
  gridColumnEvents : arr
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: this is great @Code Maniac, add on to this question. Assuming there are two sets of the array of objects i provided initially...If i had to loop through these two sets of to add the "gridColumnEvents" for each how can i do that?

Comment: @user2763557 you both to be under `gridColumnEvents` right?

Comment: each under their own "gridColumnEvents"

Answer (score 0):

You should add it as a property of an object.
like this :

```
var obj = {
gridColumnEvents:[{
    "value": "720",
    "command": "SetGridCellValue",
    "columnID": "28"
  },
  {
    "value": "331-4014",
    "command": "SetGridCellValue",
    "columnID": "29"
  },
  {
    "value": "CAR",
    "command": "SetGridCellValue",
    "columnID": "27"
  }
]
};
```